# How should the AnyChart library be used with Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, anychart

I am trying to integrate AnyChart library into my Angular 11 application but I keep getting the error:

> Property 'maps' does not exist on type 'typeof anychart'. Did you mean 'map'?

Here is how my code looks like:

```js
import {AfterViewInit, Component, OnInit, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';
import 'anychart';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-map-chart',
  templateUrl: './map-chart.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./map-chart.component.scss']
})
export class MapChartComponent implements OnInit {

  @ViewChild('chartContainer') container;

  chart= anychart.map()
  dataSet = anychart.data.set(
    [{"id":"UG.KN","value":0},
            {"id":"UG.JI","value":1},
            {"id":"UG.KU","value":2},]
  );

  constructor() {
      // set chart title
      this.chart.title("Map Title");
      this.chart.choropleth(this.dataSet);// What to put here
      // set geoIdField to 'id', this field contains in geo data meta properties
      this.chart.geoIdField('id');
      // set map color settings
      // this.chart.colorScale(anychart.scales.linearColor('#deebf7', '#3182bd'));
      this.chart.hovered().fill('#addd8e');

      this.chart.geoData(anychart.maps['uganda']);

  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.chart.container(this.container.nativeElement);
    this.chart.draw();
  }

}
```

Any pointers on how I can solve this

Answer (score 1):

You should include the map file to let it work. For details, check [the demo application](https://static.anychart.com/cdn/ts/integrations/angular6Map.zip). To launch it execute `npm install` and `npm run start`.

Answer (score 1):

Adding `declare var anychart: any` above the component using the library solved the problem